# Why results affecting left join table shipyard

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here i wrote a query with left join table shipyard. There is no connection related to this table but its affecting the results when we joined or removed, The question is why ?
Mainly its affecting OrderBook and TotalShips column.

```
    select a.sbwynum,
        a.sbnam,
        a.deleted,
        sum(if ((sh.statuscod = 'O' or sh.statuscod = 'S') and (left (
        condeldat, 4) = '2011' or left (adjdeldat, 4) = '2011' or left (
        deldat, 4) = '2011'), sh.cgt, 0)) as CurrCgt,
        count(if ((sh.statuscod = 'O' or sh.statuscod = 'S') and (left (
        condeldat, 4) = '2011' or left (adjdeldat, 4) = '2011' or left (
        deldat, 4) = '2011'), 1, NULL)) as CurrShips,
        count(if (sh.statuscod = 'O', 1, NULL)) as OrderBook,
        count(if (sh.statuscod = 'S', 1, NULL)) as TotalShips,
        a.country as coucod,
        ct.counam,
        a.fulnam,
        a.status,
        a.stoclist,
        if (sh.statuscod = 'O', 1, 2) as StatusFlag
 from shipbuilder as a
      left join
      (select sbwynum, statuscod, condeldat, adjdeldat, deldat, cgt from
      `ship` s join shiptype st on s.wytypid = st.wytypid and st.forsearch
      = 'Y' and st.searchsb = 'Y' and deleted = 'N') sh on sh.sbwynum =
      a.sbwynum
      left join country ct on ct.coucod = a.country and ct.deleted = 'N'
      left join shipyard sy on a.sbwynum = sy.sbwynum and sy.deleted != 'Y' and
      sy.syclsid != 'B'
 where a.sbwynum != '' and
       a.deleted = 'N' and
       a.status != 'FV' and
       a.country = '365'
 group by a.sbwynum
 having a.deleted = 'N'
 order by sbnam
```

Thanks a lot.....

Comment: How is it affecting it, less results or more results when it's included? Have you tried SELECT DISTINCT to see if that still gives different results? There are a couple of reasons why this could occur

Comment: when i remove its get less orderbook and totalships and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment, it means that you have a 1 to many relationship from shipbuilder to shipyard that falls within your join criteria. This should be solved with a select distinct.

**Edit** The distinct should be applied within your count statements

Comment: all records are distinct, but i have added but not affecting results.

Comment: The problem is with your count statement, that is not distinct, try changing it to count(if (distinct sh.statuscod = 'O', 1, NULL)), I don't know if that will work though, as a proof of concept, add one column where it counts distinct and then the other one where it doesn't: count(distinct sh.statuscod),count(sh.statuscod)

Comment: Just for interest sake, how did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using joins use sub queries. At least for some of the trivial joins.

Comment: any other idea, without using sub query.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is why ?

Because you have more than one row in `shipyard` with the same `sbwynum` where `deleted != 'Y' and syclsid != 'B'`.

**Update:**

Here is an example trying to explain what I mean.

Table setup:

```
create table Table1
(
  ID int,
  Name varchar(10)
)

create table Table2
(
  ID int,
  IDFromTable1 int
)
```

Table data:

```
insert into Table1 values (1, 'Name')

insert into Table2 values (1, 1)
insert into Table2 values (2, 1)
```

Count query without left join:

```
select count(T1.ID)
from Table1 as T1
```

Result:

```
-----------
1
```

Count query with left join to Table2

```
select count(T1.ID)
from Table1 as T1
  left outer join Table2 as T2
    on T1.ID = T2.IDFromTable1
```

Result:

```
-----------
2
```

Comment: Actually shipyard table left joined to shipbuilder table so it should no affect to shipbuilder table's records that is a base table and also orderbook and totalship column are counted from sh alias sub query(virtual table), So its will not affect the record at counting.  Then where is your answer is suitable according to conditon.  Any doubt ?

Comment: @J.J Updated answer with an example of what I mean.